# Not able to find the <custom>.properties file from the jar using spring boot gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar, spring-properties

Not able to find the sensitive .properties file path, when I run the jar, but from IDE it is executing, using Gradle.
sensitive. properties is in the resources folder

```
public void getConfigValue(String configKey) {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("sensitive.properties");
        
        String value = null;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("FilePath :" + resource.getURI().getPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Command used to run the jar:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test1 myservice.jar
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You'd simply call `resource.getInputStream()` to access the content…

Comment: When you run with dockerization we are not able to find the path of the file.